# Integrating Spring Security into Spring Web Application (JSON REST API)

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-security

We're currently writing a middleware using Spring Boot (1.2.6) to expose a REST API to our mobile/web applications. Middleware has no DB and is backed by some remote services of our customer.

For Login, we send username/password and a few more parameters (ip, user agent etc.) to remote services and get back some information about the user (name, last login, boolean change password flag etc..) including a session id. We wrote some beans to do this that we use in the corresponding controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", produces = "application/json")
public final class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody final LoginRequest request, final HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        final LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse();
        final LoginServiceRequest serviceRequest = new LoginServiceRequest();

        serviceRequest.setAdditionalRequestData(AdditionalRequestData.getInstance(servletRequest));
        serviceRequest.setUsername(request.getUsername());
        serviceRequest.setPassword(request.getPassword());

        final LoginData serviceResponse = userService.login(serviceRequest);

        response.setChangePassword(serviceResponse.isChangePassword());
        // setting other params here...

        return response;
    }
}
```

As far as I saw, Spring Security usually depends on servlet filters which work before the controller. For instance, if I enable formLogin in configuration, it enables `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` which handles the authentication based on the `AuthenticationManager` beans I define. However I need the authentication response in this case and we send our request parameters encoded in JSON. So it seems that filters don't work for us.

Instead, I created an `AuthenticationProvider` and `AuthenticationToken` and changed above code to something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", produces = "application/json")
public final class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager auth;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody final LoginRequest request,
        final HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws ServletException {

        final LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse();
        final Authentication authenticationToken = new CustomAuthenticationToken(
            request.getUserId(),
            request.getPassword(),
            AdditionalRequestData.getInstance(servletRequest)
        );

        final LoginData loginData = 
            ((CustomAuthenticationToken) auth.authenticate(authenticationToken)).getLoginData();

        response.setChangePassword(loginData.isChangePassword());
        // setting other params here...

        return response;
    }
}
```

The `AuthenticationProvider` is responsible for calling the `userService.login` method as well as setting the `AuthenticationToken` into `SecurityContext`.

This is our security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/version/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(Constants.ROLE_USER);
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

This manuel approach actually works. We also make use of authorities (ROLE_USER etc..) for granting access to different endpoints.

Is there a better solution to this? Do you think we lose some features of Spring Security when we do this?

Comment: Why dont you extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and override required methods ?

Comment: I've considered that option as well but couldn't find a way to make it work. Currently trying to make it work with formLogin..

Comment: Can you explain a bit more this part "*However I need the authentication response in this case and we send our request parameters encoded in JSON. So it seems that filters don't work for us.*" it doesn't make sense to me. And your "manual" approach is still using servlet filters - that's the only way Spring Security can work in web applications.

Comment: @ZoranRegvart: Please check the first code block above where my controller does the authentication with userService and return a response which is consumed by our apps. Even though the authentication takes place in filter I wasn't sure whether I could pass its output to the controller function so that I can return it to the apps. Our request parameters are encoded in JSON and I thought that would be another problem.

Comment: I've just created a CustomFilter that extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. I parse the request using Jackson mapper and authenticate the request using my AuthenticationProvider bean. Now I need the Filter to handover the request to the Controller after a successfull authentication. chain.doFilter invokes the next filter in the chain. I guess it'd work if I modify the security filter chain?